# Define jQuery Ajax Methods ($.get, $.post, $.ajax, $.getScript etc.) Base Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

We are using jQuery to perform ajax calling. We use different methods - `$.get`, `$.getScript`, `$.post` etc.

I would like perform a session check on every ajax call and once session found function should proceed to perform what is define in it's body. Rather to perform such check by explicitly call a function in every place where ajax method is used is there better way to this?

Hypothetically, assume all jQuery ajax methods have a base method, we can use that base to perform the session check. Is such thing possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use global ajax event handler:

> These methods register handlers to be called when certain events, such
>   as initialization or completion, take place for any AJAX request on
>   the page. The global events are fired on each AJAX request if the
>   global property in jQuery.ajaxSetup() is true, which it is by default.
>   Note: Global events are never fired for cross-domain script or JSONP
>   requests, regardless of the value of global.

[source](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/)

======
I think you should use `ajaxSend` event:
see here: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events
`ajaxSend` will triggered on each ajax request, and

> This global event is also triggered before the request is run

Comment: can the handlers be registered for a specific ajax method?

Comment: as this documentation say ajaxComplete will call on completion but what will be its precedences of calling before or after. I meant if I call $.get and pass it a callback on success who will call first $.ajaxComplete or the one who passed as callback function in argument.